# How to find several solutions of nonlinear equation using R e.g. nleqslv?

Tags: r, nonlinear-optimization

As far as I understand R's nonlinear equation solver nleqslv(x, fn) finds only one solution of the nonlinear equation. 
However (as Bhas commented) searchZeros function (the same package) can find my solutions depending on the starting points.

**Question:** are there some function in R which can help choosing the set of initial points for searchZeros ,which will help me to find all the solutions ?

I am interested in the case of function with  several variables.

I undestand that solution to be found pretty much depends on the initial approximation. So the brute force way is to check some reasonable grid of intial approximations. However there might be some more intelligent way to get all  the solutions ?

Comment: Have you read the manual? Package `'nleqslv` provides a function `searchZeros` that you can you can use to find different solutions. You need to provide a set of different starting values. The example in `searchZeros` shows you how to do that. Brute force is the most obvious way. Otherwise mathematical analysis of the system.

Comment: @Bhas thank you for your comment ! I am very new to R. Still there is a question how to choose grid of initial points ? Are there some functions 
 in R which can help doing it ? (My function is with two variables)

Comment: Just look at the example for `searchZeros` in the manual. You can use `runif`. If you know the minimum and maximum values for a solution the example shows how to try.